# What is the difference between meta content and link href?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

Can somebody explain me the difference between following two markups:

```
<link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition "/>
```

and

```
<meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
```

Are they fully identical? Is there any semantic difference?

Thanks a lot for your explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should amount to the same thing in your examples. Generally though, the href attribute value on the link element is subject to being [resolved](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#resolve-a-url) while the content attribute value on the meta element will be used as is.